How to handle file sent from server for user to download
I want to write a simple server-client code on NodeJS to get the file from server drive:

Server: Port 3000


Route:
 app.route('/download/:name').get(file_Controller.download);


Controller:
 file_controller.download = async (request, response) => {
     const filePath = "file_path"      
     return response.download(filePath, fileName, (err) => {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err)
       }
     });
 };




Client: Port 3001
How can I handle the response from server to let user download the file?
My current code:


API:
 export const fileApi = {
   download(params) {
     const searchParam = queryString.stringify(params)
     const url = `/download/${searchParam}`;
     return axiosClient.get(url, {params: {...params}});
   },
 };


Page:
 const download = async () => {
   try {
     return await fileApi.download({name: "file",});
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
 };



If I type the URL directly to browser like http://localhost:3000/download/file, broswer will let me download the file. However, I don't want to reveal this url to user, so I try to use above code to handle, but have no luck. How should I process?

which type of files do you want to download ?

Hopefully any file. Right now are MS Word or Excel files. I can add more later but it will not be random. Client-side will give the type in the request, and on server-side, I will use if-else to get the designated file path.

To download a file, you will need to get response as blob, then

Create a ObjectUrl using URL.createObjectURL
Create a <a> element with href linked to the ObjectUrl and click the link.
Finally clean up the resources

export const fileApi = {
    download(params) {
        const searchParam = queryString.stringify(params);
        const url = `/download/${searchParam}`;
        return axiosClient
            .get(url, {
                params: { ...params },
                responseType: 'blob' // important
            })
            .then(res => {
                const href = URL.createObjectURL(res.data); // creates a object url in memory

                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = href;
                link.setAttribute('download', params.name); // name must include a valid file extension
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();

                document.body.removeChild(link); // removing the link element
                URL.revokeObjectURL(href); // Releasing the URL from memory, this is important for optimal performance and memory usage
            });
    }
};
   

To download
const download = async () => {
    try {
        return await fileApi.download({ name: 'file.pdf' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};


Each time you call createObjectURL(), a new object URL is created, even if you've already created one for the same object. Each of these must be released by calling URL.revokeObjectURL() when you no longer need them.

